# IIS Fails for Asp.net 3.1 core site with runtime and hosting bundles installed

Tags: c#, iis

Ok I am pulling my hair out here I have come across this before. I have the following error.
But I have them installed and .net core when I go to the links try and re install it says I already have the components installed only seems to be when I publish to iis is when I have an issue.

This iis is on my local windows ten machine If I send the app up to azure its fine and works as should even though all .net components are installed including the hosting.

The application also runs fine in iis express.

I have the hosting and bundles installed. I have the configuration of my publish as follows.

[image]

> HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure  Common
>   solutions to this issue:  The application process failed to start  The
>   application process started but then stopped  The application process
>   started but failed to listen on the configured port  Troubleshooting
>   steps:  Check the system event log for error messages  Enable logging
>   the application process' stdout messages  Attach a debugger to the
>   application process and inspect

I get the following when I browse to the event viewer.
I have my application pool setup ok
[image]

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\roundtableapi\' failed to start process with
>   commandline 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\roundtableapi\RoundTableWeb.Api.exe '
>   with multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '18223'. First 30KB
>   characters of captured stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:
>   Failed to load the dll from
>   [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\roundtableapi\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
>   The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\roundtableapi\hostfxr.dll failed
>     - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
>        https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=798306 Failed to load the dll from [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\roundtableapi\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT:
>   0x800700C1 The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\roundtableapi\hostfxr.dll failed
>     - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
>        https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=798306

Comment: Sounds like you messed up the bitness, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Can you try to set application pool as 32 bit?

Comment: @LexLi Yeah that was it for me thankfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the discussion in comments,

- ASP.NET Core on IIS does not require self-contained deployment, since the runtime is always installed as part of server bundle with ASP.NET Core module.
- If you do choose self-contained deployment, then the application pool bitness must match the bitness of your bundled runtime (win-x86 in your case). This is critical as ASP.NET Core 3.x uses in-process hosting by default.

IIS Express runs your project [in a very different way](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3), so it won't show you any such issue.